# How to exclude a RewriteRule?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following RewritRule in my `.htaccess` what causes a problem for further actions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I would like to create a subdomain like `folder.example.com`

The problem is that when calling this domain it automatically will be added `www.` before `folder` so that it will be `www.folder...` because of that ReWriteRule. So my question is how can I exclude just that `folder` from that condition?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a rewrite condition excluding the subdomain from your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^folder\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. your code does not work :(

Comment: it works. in firefox there were problems. in chrome and safari it works. thanks alot. have a nice day.